# Which Starspace training mode to use for multi-level embeddings

Tags: embedding, word-embedding

I am using the StarSpace embedding framework for the first time and am unclear on the "modes" that it provides for training and the differences between them.

The options are:

- wordspace
- sentencespace
- articlespace
- tagspace
- docspace
- pagespace
- entityrelationspace/graphspace

Let's say I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
| Author | City   | Tweet_ID  | Tweet_contents                     | 
|:-------|:-------|:----------|:-----------------------------------| 
| A      | NYC    | 1         | "This is usually a short sentence" | 
| A      | LONDON | 2         | "Another short sentence"           | 
| B      | PARIS  | 3         | "Check out this cool track"        | 
| B      | BERLIN | 4         | "I like turtles"                   | 
| C      | PARIS  | 5         | "It was a dark and stormy night"   | 
| ...    | ...    | ...       | ...                                |
```

(In reality, my dataset is not a language data and looks nothing like this, but this example demonstrates the point well enough.)

I would like to **simultaneously** create embeddings from scratch (not using pre-existing embeddings at any point) for each of the following:

- Authors
- Cities
- Tweet/Sentences/Documents (EG. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.)
- Words (EG. 'This', 'is', 'usually', ..., 'stormy', 'night', etc.)

Even after reading the coumentation, it doesn't seem clear which 'mode' of starspace training I should be using.

If anyone could help me understand how to interpret the modes to help select the appropriate one, that would be much appreciated.

I would also like to know if there are conditions under which the embeddings generated using one of the modes above, would in some way be equivalent to the embeddings built using a different mode (ignoring the fact that the embeddings would be different because of the non-determinstic nature of the process.)

Thank you